# Interfacing with app-store subscription (ios)

Tags: nativescript

My app is subscription based for the app store.

Is there any plug-in/help out there how one would get a {N} app to have this feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are.

1. Easiest would be to use a module made especially for NativeScript, such as [nativescript-purchase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-purchase) (`type` seems to be `subs` for subscriptions, [see this code](https://github.com/PeterStaev/nativescript-purchase/blob/3b4e5204e209442f58ccc3a39e22a4e5d3b3442c/android/inappbilling/inappbillinghelper/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl#L51-L52))
2. Second way, and a bit more complicated, would be to use a Cocoa Pod such as [IAP Helper](https://cocoapods.org/pods/IAPHelper)
3. Most complicated way would be to build it yourself. As you've direct access to the platform's APIs when building NativeScript you can do all calls you need.

Comment: You have chosen wisely